# How do I get users who liked my Instagram post over a period of time? using Instagram graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-graph-api

I need the statistics of users who have liked/commented on my Instagram post in a certain period of time.

After hours of searching, I came to the conclusion that I could use Instagram graph API to get a list of users who had commented on Instagram post.

but I need a list of users who had liked too.
in the [Facebook Graph API docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v7.0/object/likes) it seems that such a possibility has been provided.
if it is possible how can I do that?

I tried to proceed according to the documents, but I think I made a mistake.
[here is problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62838697/100-tried-accessing-nonexisting-field-likes-on-node-type-shadowigmedia)

Comment: please add your code

Comment: @luschn https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62838697/100-tried-accessing-nonexisting-field-likes-on-node-type-shadowigmedia here is code

Comment: why would you create a separate thread? combine it to one and close the other one.

Comment: instagram does not provide such Api.